# Custom keyboard layout editor in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, keyboard-layout

I am entirely a newbie in the Linux world.

I used my own custom keyboard layout in Windows 10. Is there an app or command line or docs on how to achieve this in Linux.

I use programmer Dvorak keyboard layout changing its accented characters and all its unwanted inbuilt shortcuts build within to include as much shortcuts possible to use in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [Xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap) It's the Arch Wiki, but the program is (I would think) available in Fedora.

Comment: I found that Xmodmap doesn't work for wayland and had to use xkb to achieve that . Anyway thanks :)