# Create own keyboard layout linux debian

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use workman p with own shuffled keys for ergonomics and statistical reasons (language mix)

- on Windows I use keyboard layout creator
- on osx I used a xml file where I was able to configure the mappings
- on linux (debian) I haven't been able to find a way to really customize the key mappings.
  I found the packages below but all it seems to allow is, to change to
  another  preset language.

  `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`
  `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
  `https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard`

Is there a way to actually have a map which either builds onto an existing language and changes the keys

```
a->x
b->y
```

or something generic like:

```
(the_technical_address_of_key_which_has_label_a)->x
(the_technical_address_of_key_which_has_label_b)->y
```

in that case - how to address the keys?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried ukulele?  https://software.sil.org/ukelele/ this software should do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: At the very least you should descibe *how* to use the software to solve the problem as asked in the question. [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). How does this tool achieve what is asked? How do you use it? How do you set it up?

Comment: ... unfortunately that's just for osx

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1652566/696498)
the question considers fedora, the answer arch, and looks good on debian as well.

There you'll find a way to create a config file with `xmodmap` which you can adapt easily.

Some more insight for the config file can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Xmodmap/)

```
keycode  16 = 7 slash bar backslash

# The action of the first string is the text/function that the key produces when pressed once.
# The second character string is generated when the shift signal is also sent, which is usually done by the ⇧ key.
# The third string describes the action taken when sending the Mode_switch signal at the same time, typically by pressing the Alt key at the same time.
# The fourth string describes the action of pressing the key and sending ⇧ and mode_switch at the same time.
```